# android: got error value on listview pick

Tags: android

i have listview that connect to database.

when i pick row i get the same id.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        showDialog(DELETE_ROW);
    }


else if (id==2)
{
  builder.setMessage(c.getString(0)); <-- here i get error id - same id all the time
  builder.setTitle("AAA");
  builder.setIcon(R.drawable.no);
  builder.setCancelable(false);
  builder.setPositiveButton("yes ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); <-- here i get the real id - what i need
     }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
      return;
    }
   });
}
```

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you will have to use a final Variable.

```
public final int my_id=0;

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
    my_id=id;
    showDialog(DELETE_ROW);
}
```

Now

```
else if (my_id==2)
{
 ......
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
 {
  my_id=id; // Assigning the Value
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }
 ...
}
```

Now you can use my_id to check the Value.

Comment: i have same problem, i try this but the Correct value come only after i press [yes] or [no] on the dialogbox and i need it before. how do to it ?

Comment: @Gali: if you want the Row id Replace my_id=id; with my_id=position; in onListItemClick.